# PCI card compatibilty

Tags: drivers

I am coming from the Mac world, where I'd be able to check if a PCI card (for whatever use) is compatible with a given Mac.

I now have a PC, (A Dell Optiplex 780 desktop) and would like to install a PCI card to get more internal SATA ports.

How would I find out is a given card is going to have compatibility issues, or if Ubuntu (using 16.04) will either know how to talk to them or be able to easily load the needed drivers, if any?

Even the comments from Windows users will vary. One rating for a given card will say it worked upon rebooting, another for same card will say that drivers were needed.

Comment: Do you already have the card?

Comment: RE: different comments about same card from different users, it may be the same model but a different card (maybe changed the controller on board, or a firmware difference can cause compatibility issues)

Comment: No. There are a few to choose from, and I’m looking for a way to avoid a bad purchase or a lot of frustration.